# Cannot recieve incoming mail with Postfix when using a regex canonical recipient map

Tags: postfix

I have a test server set up at mail.ans.co52.com running Postfix with a regex canonical recipient map:

/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical-regexp:

```
/[0-9]+@mail\.ans\.co52\.com/ catchall
```

I need to be able to forward messages sent to NNNN@mail.ans.co52.com to catchall@mail.ans.co52.com.

Sending email directly to catchall@mail.ans.co52.com works fine, but if I send mail to 4403@mail.ans.co52.com it fails with this log message:

```
Dec 13 07:06:19 ans-www postfix/smtpd[16812]: connect from unknown[12.5.114.26]
Dec 13 07:06:19 ans-www postfix/smtpd[16812]: setting up TLS connection from unknown[12.5.114.26]
Dec 13 07:06:19 ans-www postfix/smtpd[16812]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[12.5.114.26]: TLSv1 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
Dec 13 07:06:20 ans-www postfix/smtpd[16812]: 0C5087E077: client=unknown[12.5.114.26], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=register
Dec 13 07:06:20 ans-www postfix/cleanup[16815]: 0C5087E077: message-id=<op.v6foc0jc9dzlfc@macdaddy.local>
Dec 13 07:06:20 ans-www postfix/qmgr[16801]: 0C5087E077: from=<register@mail.ans.co52.com>, size=827, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 13 07:06:20 ans-www postfix/smtpd[16812]: disconnect from unknown[12.5.114.26]
Dec 13 07:06:20 ans-www postfix/smtp[16803]: certificate verification failed for mail.ans.company52.com[205.186.183.147]:25: untrusted issuer /C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
Dec 13 07:06:21 ans-www postfix/smtp[16803]: 0C5087E077: to=<4403@mail.ans.company52.com>, relay=mail.ans.company52.com[205.186.183.147]:25, delay=1.2, delays=0.2/0/0.9/0.15, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host mail.ans.company52.com[205.186.183.147] said: 451 Temporary local problem - please try later (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

What does "451 Temporary local problem" mean, and why would it work for messages sent directly to catchall@mail.ans.co52.com and not 4403@mail.ans.co52.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does mean:

```
Dec 13 07:06:20 ans-www postfix/smtp[16803]: certificate verification failed for mail.ans.company52.com[205.186.183.147]:25: untrusted issuer /C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
```

Your certificate is not valid (whatever causes this) but so Postfix defers the delivery/sending. Fix it.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it works for messages sent directly to catchall@mail.ans.co52.com but not 4403@mail.ans.co52.com. This is a temporary domain and I'm using a self-signed certificate for development and testing.

Comment: @JonathonHill If you disable the certificate thing, you will see that Postfix _is_ able to receive mails with regex canonical maps. Your problem _is_ the certificate.

Comment: Well, that seems to have fixed it. I got an SSL cert from StartSSL.com, and added the StartSSL and Experian CA bundles and added it to my CA bundle.